# Get Search query Suggestions from the search box and the ones at the bottom on Google SERP

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to get the strings suggested by google when you start typing a search query in **the form of drop down** and also get the Suggested **search queries at the bottom** of the SERP.

Is there any way I could do this using app Engine.

I am only interested in the suggestions ,I dont to scrape anything else from the webpage.

I would prefer to save this preferably in tuple.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give this a go.

Firstly you'll need to find a way to query the search interface itself (SERP). We'll call that `run_search` You probably won't be able to use App Engine to run that code, not for very long anyway. They don't like automated queries much.

Anyway, something like [Mechanize](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet) would help you with that. You'll need a big range of IP's to run it from as you'll soon run into the "*We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries..*" problem. So you won't be able to run it on app-engine itself, really, as they've already seen that one coming I suspect...

Then once you've got that set up you'll need to start running your actual queries.

You'll need something like *"every_word_in_your_chosen_language.txt"*.

This will help with that: [SCOWL](http://wordlist.aspell.net/)

Then make a loop like:

```
    for word in language:
        result = run_search(word)
        output = (word, result)
```

Where `run_search` is as described above. You then have the required data in "output", a **tuple** as requested.

Of course `run_search` will return a `list` (the SERP returns multiple suggestions, remember?) so you'll have to save that list in the tuple. But that's ok. Don't forget to add in code that checks if you are just getting a "We're sorry..." message so you can renew your IP!

Of course, suggestions are also returned for single letters, numbers and even Mr Snowman ☃ so you'll need to break the words down into prefixes, starting with a single letter to whatever length you find that still returns useful results.

```
    for prefix in prefixes:
        result = run_search(prefix)
        output = (prefix, result)
```

Where `prefixes` is simply a list of all prefix combinations in your chosen language. E.G.

Aa
Ab
Ac
...
Aar
Aap
etc.

The python slice operator will come in handy for making that list.

I don't know what you intend to do with the data, once you have it, but I'd be surprised if it was not the IP of Google. So you might also need more then a random programmer's advice later on!

Comment: A trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be an appropriate data structure to load the word list into. Then a full traversal of it, stopping at every node, will produce a list of all words and all prefixes.